# SQL database not restoring on Openshift

Tags: openshift

I have an issue. I have created a snapshot on openshift with the command:

```
rhc snapshot save -a {appName}
```

However when I now run:

```
rhc snapshot restore -a {appName} -f {/path/to/snapshot/appName.tar.gz}
```

it only restores my files but not the SQL database? Any ideas what could be going wrong?

Comment: If you extract the .tar.gz archive, is the sql database there?  What is the exact output from that command to restore the snapshot?

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess you're trying to migrate from a non-scaled application to a scaled application, or vice-versa. The `rhc snapshot restore` procedure does not work when transitioning between a non-scaled and a scaled application.